Determine $L^k$ where $L_{i,j}=\delta_{i,j}$

Let $L$ be the $m\times m$ matrix with $1$'s on the super-diagonal, i.e.,
$$L_{i,j}=\delta_{i,j-1}$$
for $1\le i,j\le m$. Determine the entries of $L^k$ for each integer $k\ge 0$ and show that $L^k =0$ for all $k\ge m$.

I can 'solve' the second part of this problem using induction by explicitly multiplying $\mathcal O$ with $L$, but for that I need to prove the first part which forms the base case. This is where I am having problems.
I would like to take this opportunity to ask a more general question - how do we approach problems of this type (where a matrix is only partially populated and we are asked about its powers) in general?

The second part is actually easier than the first ; the characteristic polynomial of the matrix can be seen to be (quite easily)  $\chi_L(\lambda)=\lambda^m$. And by Cayley Hamilton, a matrix must satisfy its own characteristic polynomial, so $L^m=0$ (and hence this holds for greater powers). As a general hint, have you tried looking at powers of L?

@J.D Nice, I didn't think of Cayley Hamilton! I have not explicitly tried multiplying the matrices, I was sort of hoping for some more general trick...

Hint: Have you tried calculating $L^2$ for some sufficiently general $m$ to see what's going on, say $m=5$?

Another possible way to look at it: $L$ acts on the standard basis as $L e_1 = 0, L e_2 = e_1, L e_3 = e_2, \ldots, L e_m = e_{m-1}$.  Might that help you in determining what $L^k$ might look like?

@DanielSchepler developing on your second hint, $L^k e_1=L^k e_2=...=L^k e_k=0$, $L^k e_{k+1}=e_k$ and so on. So, $L^k_{i,j}=\delta_{i,j-k}$. Is that right?
